# Vim : Can't set up Ctags

Tags: vim, ctags

I have question about setting up Ctags/Vim.

First, I did

```
$ brew install ctags
```

and in my working directory

```
$ pwd
~/projects/rails/rep

$ ctags -R
```

then I got `tags` file in my working directory; rep.

and in my `.vimrc` file

```
set tags=tags;/
```

On the method I want to jump, I did `Ctrl + ]`, but I got

```
E426: tag not found: method_name
```

I have no idea which is the reason I cannot use ctags...

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure current directory in vim is correct. `set tags=tags;/` will make vim search for tags file in current directory and all parent directories till root. In vim check what `:pwd` is?

Comment: The created tags file is a text file. Please open it with a text editor and check if the method you wanted to jump to is included in your tags file at all. If not you may need to set the path to your source files when calling ctags.

Comment: @Habi I checked the tags file, and it does include the methods I want to jump. Thanks.

Comment: @AshwaniDausodia The directory setting of `set tags=tags;/` was wrong. That was the reason of this error. I changed it to the right directory and it finally worked. Thanks.